# Can't connect URL JSON Parser

Tags: java, android, json

On my JSON Project, i have a little problem. My app : we get an boolean from a JSON Data (web). But the function who initialize internet doesn't want work.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.mypckg/com.package.mypckg.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
at com.package.mypckg.MainActivity.readFromUrl(MainActivity.java:80)
at com.package.mypckg.MainActivity.checkIfOnline(MainActivity.java:63)
at com.package.mypckg.MainActivity.detectonline(MainActivity.java:47)
at com.package.mypckg.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

This problem come from `scanner = new Scanner(page.openStream());`.

I didn't know why this didn't work. This is my function :

```
  private static String readFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
        URL page = new URL(url);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try{
            //scanner = new Scanner(page.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            scanner = new Scanner(page.openStream());
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                sb.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        }finally{
            if (scanner!=null)
                scanner.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

How i can resolve it ? Thank you

Comment: Look at this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/1889768) this explains what you are facing and how to overcome the issue.

Comment: Add below line in onCreate method
`StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`
else create a AsynTask or Thread

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is that your are running `Network` on `Main Thread`. 
As `UI` is rendered on `Main Thread` android does not allow to run `network` related operation on `main Thread`. Use `AsyncTask` for running your `network` operations. You will get lot of examples of how to use `asyncTask` on stackoverflow iteself.